# Want the variable from a script.cs component of an object which is collided

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to access the variable(allowWalk) of an object which has collided with isTrigger object.
below is the script of isTrigger object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieTrack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xPos;
    public float zPos;

    void Start(){
        xPos = transform.position.x;
        zPos = transform.position.z;
    }
     void Update() {
        //transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, transform.position.y, zPos);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Zombie"){
            other.GetComponent<"ZombieAI">().allowWalk = false;
            this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
            
                if(Random.Range(1,3) == 1){
                    xPos = Random.Range(transform.position.x + 5, transform.position.x + 10);
                }else{
                    xPos = Random.Range(transform.position.x - 5, transform.position.x - 10);
                }

                if(Random.Range(1,3) == 1){
                    zPos = Random.Range(transform.position.z + 5, transform.position.z + 10);
                }else{
                    zPos = Random.Range(transform.position.z - 5, transform.position.z - 10);
                }

            other.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idle");
            StartCoroutine(Wait());
            // other.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("walk");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, transform.position.y, zPos);
        this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
    }
    
}
```

In OnTriggerEnter is there different way for `other.GetComponent<"ZombieAI">().allowWalk = false;`. ZombieAI.cs is the script.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: No "" for the type => GetComponent<ZombieAI>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a component via `GetComponent<T>`, but you're passing a string to the generics argument. You should have an error because of this.

```cs
other.GetComponent<ZombieAI>().allowWalk = false;
```